# Python progress bar for PyGithub clone function

Tags: python, git, progress-bar, tqdm

How can I see the progress of a cloning process? tqdm module does not work for single line statements. Is there a git argument that I should add? Any references would help. Thanks.

```
import git

#clone to local system
git.Repo.clone_from(repo_url,path, branch='master')
```

Answer (score 2):

The [GitPython source code](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/60acfa5d8d454a7c968640a307772902d211f043/git/repo/base.py#L1014) includes:

```py
def clone_from(cls, url, to_path, progress=None, env=None, multi_options=None, **kwargs):
```

with progress defined in [`git.remote.Remote.push`](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/30387f16920f69544fcc7db40dfae554bcd7d1cc/git/remote.py#L821-L834)

```py
:param progress:
    Can take one of many value types:
        * None to discard progress information
        * A function (callable) that is called with the progress information.
          Signature: ``progress(op_code, cur_count, max_count=None, message='')``.
        * An instance of a class derived from ``git.RemoteProgress`` that
          overrides the ``update()`` function.
```

You can see an example of a [progress function here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62623518/6309) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53999435/6309).