# How do I set a progress bar when cloning a repository with GitPython?

Tags: python, git, progress-bar, tqdm, gitpython

I would like to set a progress bar when cloning a repository with GitPython, by using some library such as tqdm.
For the moment I wrote the following code in the main.py:

```
import git

...some code...

git.Repo.clone_from(url=repo_url, to_path=dir_cloned_repo, progress=CloneProgress())
```

Then I made a class called CloneProgress, in a clone_progress.py file, which contains the following code:

```
from git import RemoteProgress
from tqdm import tqdm

class CloneProgress(RemoteProgress):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pbar = tqdm()

    def update(self, op_code, cur_count, max_count=None, message=''):
        self.pbar.total = max_count
        self.pbar.n = cur_count
        self.pbar.refresh()
```

The problem is that, when testing out the code it basically starts the progress bar, and when it reaches 100% it then resets to 0% to download other stuff.
And it does that multiple times, depending on the repository.

For instance, I tried to clone the repository https://github.com/apache/incubator-iotdb by using the code above.
At first, it starts showing the following progress bar:

```
39%| ... | 59148.0/151621.0 [05:25<08:29, 181.55it/s]
```

After completing the progress bar above, it resets itself and starts again:

```
6%| ... | 288.0/4796.0 [06:19<1:39:03, 1.32s/it]
```

As you can see it's changing the current and total elements, but it keeps the time previously calculated unaltered in the first iteration.

My aim is to actually create a progress bar for the overall cloning process, avoiding the progress bar to reset itself.

Any suggestion is appreciated.
If you do know some other library for making a progress bar which you think it's better you're welcome to share your knowledge.

Comment: The reason it resets is that cloning happens in several stages changing. And whenever a new stage starts, max_count changes to a new number and cur_count is reset. See answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/51045540 for examples of creating a new bar for each stage using `rich` and `alive-progress`.